# Using perturbation theory or small oscillation approximation in Harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

Let us assume, we are given the following potential,

$$V(x)=\frac{1}{2}ax^2-2x+\epsilon x^3$$

We need to find the energy levels of a particle bound in this potential

Let us think of the **ground level** for now. As we can see, the first term in the potential resembles a **harmonic oscillator**, so I can possibly use **perturbation theory** on the second and the third terms to come up with an approximate value of the ground level energy of this particle.

We'd get a ground state energy of the form,

$$ E_0 = \frac{1}{2}\hbar \sqrt{\frac{a}{m}} + E_x^1 + E_x^3$$

The two terms, in the end, come from the *perturbations due to the linear and cubic terms.

However, I've also recently read about small oscillations.

We are usually given an **arbitrary potential**, and we approximate it into an **oscillator potential** about the **local minima**, using

$$ 
\begin{align}
\left.\frac{dV(x)}{dx}\right|_{x_{0}} &= 0 \\[5pt] 
\left.\frac{d^2V(x)}{dx^2}\right|_{x_{0}} &= K \\[5pt]
\omega = \sqrt{\frac{K}{m}}
\end{align}
$$

This is how we obtain the value of angular frequency for a random potential, in small oscillations.

Now, the potential in our given problem can also be approximated like in small oscillations. We can obtain the minima at around $x=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+24 \epsilon }-a}{6 \epsilon }\approx 2/a -12\epsilon/a$, and by differentiating the potential twice, we get :

$$K=a+\frac{12\epsilon}{a}.$$

This equates to an angular frequency
$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{a^2+12\epsilon}{a}}{m}}$$

Using this **frequency**, we can also calculate the *ground state energy level* to be :

$$ E_0 = \frac{1}{2}\hbar \sqrt{\frac{\frac{a^2+12\epsilon}{a}}{m}}$$

Thus using two different methods, **perturbation theory**, and **small oscillations**, I've obtained two approximations of the ground state energy level.

Which of the above methods is wrong, and why can I not use that ?

Comment: What do you get for $E_x^1$ and $E_x^3$?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I've considered first order perturbation for this, and $E_x^1 = 0$ and $E_x^3 = 0$, because of odd symmetry. However, I've not yet learnt second order perturbation theory , but I know I'm supposed to get additional terms. I just want to know, why can I not use small oscillation approximation of potential, instead of perturbation theory.

Comment: Why do you think one method must be wrong? You haven't evaluted one of them, they could yet give the same answer.

Comment: There are several issues with your proposed solution.  First is that the minimum is not near $x=1$ but rather at $x=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+24 \epsilon }-a}{6 \epsilon }\approx 2/a -12\epsilon/a$.  The second derivative evaluated at that point yields 
\begin{align}
k=\sqrt{a^2+24\epsilon}
\approx a+\frac{12\epsilon}{a}\, .
\end{align}
Another difficulty is that $\epsilon$ is not dimensionless so you can't really use an expansion   in powers of $\epsilon$ as this will results in terms that do not have dimensions of energy.  Even with this I'm not sure why I can't get the two methods to agree.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you can assume that the "linear" term is a perturbation of the quadratic term, as there is not "small" parameter multiplying it. I wonder if it might be better to rewrite your potential as $$V(x) = \frac{1}{2} a \left( x - \frac{2}{a} \right)^2 - \frac{2}{a} + \epsilon x^3,$$ and then treat the $\epsilon$ term as the perturbation.

Comment: I have to admit that my "physical intuition" is telling me that both these methods should agree, but I wonder if that's even possible. The first (and higher) order perturbations depend in general on the energy level $n$ that's being perturbed: however, in the "small oscillations" approximation I see no way to include the *quantum* energy level into the solution. In other words, the perturbation that you find using this method is the same for *all* energy levels, isn't it? But that can't be right, can it? Anyway, at least the two methods match to first order!

Comment: @ZeroTheHero yeah, I'm sorry I failed to see that. By mistake i did the calculations assuming values of $a$, and $\epsilon$. Anyway, I have made the edits to my question, thanks ! Moreover, I know that both methods are ultimately approximations, but it is still not clear, why one method is preferred and the other not used.

Comment: @Philip I added the linear term as a perturbation because I saw it in many course materials. If we perform second-order perturbation on the linear term, we obtain the $\frac{-2}{a}$ term. That is why I used that as a perturbation. However, in this case if we assume small oscillation approximation ( ignoring the cubic term), the linear term simply vanishes, while calculating the second derivative, and so the angular frequency remains the same, and so does energy. We don't get the extra $\frac{-2}{a}$ term. However, using small oscillations, we do get the shifted origin.

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay When you do a perturbation, you are essentially doing a series expansion in some small parameter, and I believe in this case it is $\epsilon$. My point is just that I am not certain you can assume the linear term to be a "perturbation" of the quadratic term, since they are both the same order in $\epsilon$. To me, your problem is just as shifted harmonic oscillator with a cubic term. That being said, I agree that this doesn't address your fundamental question as to why both methods don't give similar answers.